# how to create a bucket in gsutil for uploading sql dump file in cloudsql.?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql, bucket, gsutil

I am using windows-7 64-bit OS. I am trying to upload my sql dump file to Cloud SQL. It  requires gsutil tool to create the bucket and upload it. but how do I create the bucket using gsutil?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More info about GSTIL can be found here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil

gsutil mb gs://-INSERT BUCKET NAME HERE-

Note:

> The mb command creates a new bucket. Google Cloud Storage has a single namespace, so you will not be allowed to create a bucket with a name already in use by another user. You can, however, carve out parts of the bucket name space corresponding to your company’s domain name (see “gsutil help naming”).

Which means the bucket must have a unique name across all buckets created in Google.

Comment: can u tel me more detail.? because i tried many times. i dont know where to type that command gsutil mb..... i went into gsutil directory and typed the command. but it not working.

Comment: Do you still need more help or did the other answer work for you?

Comment: i have created a bucket. thanks for you help. but am not clear about importing the .sql fine into cloudsql. can  you help me please.

Comment: i have uploaded successfully. thanks for your help. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Storage Browser in [Google Developer Console](http://console.developers.google.com) to do that. Assuming you're using App Engine, a default bucket should have been created for your app automatically: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/setup

Comment: thanks mars. and am facing a new problem now. when i open my GAE launcher it showing error. "Errors occurred, See the logfile 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\launcher\GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe.log' for details." and googled for the solution and deleted sone log files in c:\users\user-name\google\. can u please help me out in this.

Comment: Does it happen every time when you open/close the launcher? Or only when you try to start/stop the app? Also what version of Python do you have?

Comment: python version 2.7. no it happened suddenly. it showing when i start the GAE launcher. even i re-installed it am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Storage Bucket Can create using UI.**

Go to Storage Bucket -> Click On **Create** Button.Then provide name and click on Create button.

It will create Bucket

**Using Gsutil Command**

```
  gsutil mb gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

Set the following optional flags to have greater control over the creation of your bucket:

```
 gsutil mb -p PROJECT_ID -c STORAGE_CLASS -l BUCKET_LOCATION -b on gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

Reference : https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets#storage-create-bucket-gsutil